# How to access Specific Value in Array in powerapps (Workflow)?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am new to power platform apps. So I am looking for a solution for the following scenario.
I have a set of arrays if I am selecting a specific value from that I need the corresponding value .i.e. If I select Department as **Mech**, I need the corresponding **HOD** value. Once I have received the corresponding value need to drop a mail on the success scenario and failure just a message.
So can anyone help me in how to write workflow for this?

Example:
[
{
"Dept":"CSE",
"HOD":"Arun"
},
{"Dept","MECH",
"HOD":"Kishor"
},
{"Dept":"EEE",
"HOD":"Lilly"
}
]

Required Output :
Kishor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic scenario that shows you what to do.

#### Flow

[image: Flow]

There are three steps that I used to demonstrate.

1. The first is simply a variable that contains your data.
2. The next filters the array to the single value where the `Dept` property is equal to `MECH`
3. The third step will extract the value of the `HOD` property for the first value found from the filter.

Caveat: There's no error checking here but you can bake that in as required.

##### Filter My Array

[image: Step 2]

This is self explanatory apart from the left hand side (`Dept`) check.  The expression in this field is ...

```
item()['Dept']
```

##### Initialize HOD Value

[image: Step 3]

The expression here is ...

```
if(equals(length(body('Filter_Array')), 1), first(body('Filter_Array'))['HOD'], '')
```

... basically, if it finds that the length of the array is equal to 1 (i.e. it only found one item when it filtered) then it will get the value of the `HOD` property for the first (and only) item.  Else, it will return a blank string.

Comment: Thank you so much Skin for the entire flow. I am replicating the same steps which you posted,but i am facing this error" The variable 'Departments' of type 'Array' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'String'. The variable 'Departments' only supports values of types 'Array'." [link](https://paste.pics/a2e6ffa172237a77353e0dbe960c75d8)

Comment: The JSON in your question is wrong. I thought it was just a typo but maybe you’re using a variant of it. You have a comma where you shouldn’t have a comma. I’d fix it for you but someone has already edited your question and it’s awaiting another reviewer. You need to fix this up … "Dept","MECH" … the comma should be a colon. I’m assuming that’s your problem because I faced the same thing and had to correct it.

Comment: skin, Thank you your flow is working if set **MECH** in array filter value field. can you show me how to extract the **dynamic value**, when i am trying to extract value dynamic i am seeing empty array as output. Screenshot [link](https://snipboard.io/3OFIuR.jpg)

Comment: Ok but the first thing to do would be to accept the answer and then given that question is answered, it’d be better to open a new question given that’ll require a different answer.

Comment: skin,If you could answer here it would be better or if you could share me by any means of link it would be great help for me

Comment: It’s hard to answer when I don’t actually know what you’re wanting me to solve. Seriously, asking another question is the best way, that way the community can help solve if I can’t AND you can target your issue. This question doesn’t ask that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Select action (Data Operation) and set the input to your array of objects.

Set the map to have a key of item()[‘Dept’] and value of item()[‘HOD’].

This should give you an array of objects each keyed by the value of “Dept”, e.g. “MECH” and the value of “HOD”

Update with pictures:
[image]
[image]

Not sure how far you wanna drill down.
The first Select is:
Key:
if(equals(item()['dept'], 'mech'), item()['dept'], '')
Value:
if(equals(item()['dept'], 'mech'), item()['hod'], '')

Comment: it will not work. I have added the screenshot. Please refer [link](https://snipboard.io/3OFIuR.jpg)

Comment: @Avi I’ve updated my answer.  I don’t see a select action in your picture.